# Inside Python subtitles to player pysrt and vlc

Tags: video, libvlc, subtitle

i am trying to make a python program that creates random subtitles every time you see the movie.I use vlc.py 2.2 and pysrt. I want to pass the created subtitles without the need to create a file and then load it.

pysrt.SubRipItems are list like classes, with the inspect.getargspec() function giving me:

```
ArgSpec(args=['self', 'index', 'start', 'end', 'text', 'position'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(0, None, None, '', ''))
```

the print() gives me:

```
1
00:00:00,100 --> 00:02:18,828
Hello World!
```

and the type():

```
class 'str'
```

But no subtitle appear, and no error.

Here is my code until now:

```
import vlc
import pysrt
import inspect


file = pysrt.SubRipFile(encoding='utf-8')
sub = pysrt.SubRipItem(1, start='00:00:0,100', end='00:02:18,828', text="Hello World!")
file.append(sub)

SubString=str(file[0])

print(SubString)
print (type(SubString))
print (inspect.getargspec(pysrt.SubRipItem))

Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new('Test.avi')
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
player.video_set_subtitle_file(SubString)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `python-vlc` package is a wrapper for the VLC C library, so you cannot pass Python fancy objects to it.

You can only add a subtitle by its file path. For this, you should use the media [`add_options`](http://olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.Media-class.html#add_options) method, rather than `video_set_subtitle_file`. You can set several of the options the `vlc` command accepts (available with `vlc --help --longhelp --full-help`), but with no double dash and an equal sign between the option name and its value.

```
Media.add_options("sub-file={}".format("path/to/your/subtitle/file"))
```

Since you should save your subtitle file to disk first, you can use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` as a context manager, to make sure it will be deleted after. Of course, you cannot use a pseudo-file like `io.FileIO`.